Can citus distribute table and assign trigger in same session?
Citus does not natively support triggers on distributed tables, but there is an official workaround on their site.
The way to do this is to

create the table (without the trigger)
create function the trigger will execute
call run_command_on_shards with the string command to create the trigger

The following is code is, more or less, from the citus documented workaround.
drop table if exists events;

CREATE TABLE events (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  description text NOT NULL,
  author name NOT NULL
);

SELECT create_distributed_table('events', 'id');

-- First create a function that all these triggers will use.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_author() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    NEW.author := current_user;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Now create a trigger for every placement

SELECT run_command_on_shards(
  'events',
  $cmd$
    CREATE TRIGGER events_set_author BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON %s
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_author()
  $cmd$
);

The problem is, that if I run this all in a single transaction, I get the error (on each shard when calling run_command_on_shards): relation ""events_153432"" does not exist.
However, if I create/distribute the table first, then set the trigger, it works.
From this observation, there is a couple possible causes, but maybe someone with better understanding of citus details knows what might be the cause and solution.

Because the table is created in a transaction, and the transaction does not commit until the end of the session, there is nothing that can be distributed at that time, so no table exists in the shards.
-or-
The call to create_distributed_table is nondeterministic/asynchronous, so when that function completes, the table has not actually been distributed, but rather queued for eventual distribution.

Thoughts??
